# Exposing variables from a library with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I don't seem to understand how webpack works. I would like to create a plain javascript library with some reusable components that I can use in other applications and in script tags in the html. So I tried to make a very simple library that exposes one variable containing a string. Should be simple I thought, but can't seem to get it to work.

My webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/app.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'main.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        library: {
            name: 'mypack',
            type: 'umd',
        },
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    devServer: {
        watchContentBase: true,
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        port: 9000
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test:/\.css$/,
                use:['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
}
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "mypack",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "./src/app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "start": "webpack ./src/app.js -d eval --watch --mode development",
    "dev": "npx webpack serve"
  },
  "author": "me",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.44.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.7.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "style-loader": "^3.2.1"
  }
}
```

My src/app.js

```
let myvar = "test";

export {myvar};
```

My dist/index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"><title>test</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Test
        <script>
          console.log(mypack.myvar);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

mypack.myvar gives an 'undefined' in the console. mypack seem to be an empty object {}.
How can I access myvar in my package? What am I doing wrong?

Of course, this is only a dummy, in reality I would like to expose objects from the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it seems to be a problem with the webppack-dev-server.

If I comment out the line 'contentBase: path.resolve(_dirname, 'dist'),' from the webpack.config.js, copy the index.html to the root of my package and change the script tag source to "dist/index_bundle.js" then it works.

Not sure what is going on there, the script seems to load just fine in the situation above (in the sourceview in the browser, I can click the link and I see the generated javascript) but doesn't seem to be working at all. But that's another question.